# How can I prove that this sequence is Cauchy?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have x<sub>n</sub> is a sequence with the following properties:
There exists a number, K, 0 < K < 1, such that for all n ∈ N(natural numbers), |x<sub>n+2</sub>-x<sub>n+1</sub>| $\le$ K|x<sub>n+1</sub>-x<sub>n</sub>|.
How can I prove it's Cauchy? What I know about Cauchy sequences is that by definition: for all ϵ>0 , there exists N such that for all n,m>N, |x<sub>m</sub>−x<sub>n</sub>|<ϵ

Comment: It was, I just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=|x_1-x_0|$. Then we have $|x_2-x_1|\leq Ka$, and inductively, $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq K^na$. Since $0<K<1$, what can we say about the sequence $(K^na)_{n=1,2,\ldots}$?

Comment: |x_m - x_m-1|+...+|x_n+1 - x_n| <= (1/K)^-(m-1)+...+(1/K)^-n?

Comment: There is no need to sum all of those differences. Just note that they go to zero.

Comment: so do I then conclude by pointing out that aK^n < ϵ?

Comment: That works, especially if you know *why* it’s true that sufficiently large powers of a positive number less than 1 become arbitrarily small.

Comment: Actually it is necessary to sum the terms, since for Cauchy sequences the bound between subsequent terms going to zero is not sufficient. Log(n) is a counterexample.

Comment: Geometric sequence summation sound do the trick to get a bound on the sum.

Comment: Of course, you’re right. What was I thinking?